# Create dynamic list of attendees in Google Apps Script calendar event

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Trying to add a list of comma separated email addresses to a Google Apps Script  in order to email those people of a new calendar event.

Seems that I can statically include emails using the format

```
attendees: [
  {email: 'alice@example.com'},
  {email: 'bob@example.com'}
],
```

But I cannot figure out how to take a csv string and convert those entries to a list of email addresses.

```
var calId = 'xxxx@resource.calendar.google.com';
  var event = {
    sendNotifications: true,
    sendUpdates: "all",
    summary: summary, 
    start: {
      date: eventDate
    },
    end: {
      date: eventDate
    }
  };

  var adds = response.getResponseText();
  if( adds.length > 0 ){
    //Create Mail List
    var addresses = adds.split(',');
    for( var i=0; i < addresses.length; i++){
      var addee=addresses[i].trim();
      Logger.log(addee);
      event.attendees.push( "email: "+addee);
    }
  event = Calendar.Events.insert( event, calId, {sendNotifications: true} 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your problem could comes from :

```
event.attendees = new List<EventAttendee>();
...
event.attendees.email=addee;
```

In my understanding, this array will be empty, and it's probably not possible to add email this way... I didn't try it but this code looks better :

```
    ArrayList<EventAttendee> attendees = new ArrayList<EventAttendee>();
...
    attendees.add(new EventAttendee().setEmail(addee)); // in the loop
...
    event.setAttendees(attendees);
```

Comment: Sorry Tristan, the EventAttendee list was invalid in the original code posted. What I really need is to be able to dynamically take the csv email addresses and include them as separate emails to the event object. Per google app script api, the attendees should be a list with the form------>  attendees: [
  {email: 'alice@example.com'},
  {email: 'bob@example.com'}
], which is part of the event object.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late but maybe the answer could help someone else.
You need to do 2 things:
1. you need to add the attendees as a property id inside "event" so that when you try to push an element, it won't say 'undefined'. Something like this:

```
var event = {
summary: subject,
location: dir,
description: (part1+'\n'+part2linebreak),
start: {
  dateTime: start.toISOString()
},
end: {
  dateTime: end.toISOString()
},
attendees: [

  ],
// Red background. Use Calendar.Colors.get() for the full list.
colorId: 11
};
```

attendees is created, but it's empty.

2.Now we enter data into 'attendees' like this:

```
for(var i=0; i<mailist.length; i++){
event.attendees.push({email: mailist[i]});
}
```

at least that how I did it :)
also sendUpdates: "all" or sendNotifications: true go outside the event, like this:

```
event = Calendar.Events.insert(event, calid,{senUpdates: "all"});
```

cheers